# Xcode 5 - Launch Images not loading in iPad of iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode5

I am developing an iPhone app on Xcode 5, it's having iOS 7 design but deployment target is iOS 6.0.

My question is concerned to Splash Screen of the app. It is working fine in iPhone.

[image]

Now when i tried to run app on my iPad, it is not loading the Splash Screen/Launch Images and It is showing blank screen instead of actual splash screen image, then from Rootviewcontroller it's working fine.

[image: Xcode general info image.]

I have set the Launch Images in Xcode  "Images.xcassets" folder.

[image: Xcode Images.xcassets Launch image section.]

Please suggest, what process should I follow to prepare Splash Screen on iPad properly ?

What is the way to set Splash Screen of an iPhone app for an iPad in Xcode 5 ?

Comment: even if it is an iPhone app the launch image should be visible.

Comment: clean and build again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old pattern would be helpful for the iPhone app developed in X-code 5. To implement this-

Uncheck from Launch Image Assets

[image: Screen shot of assets]

and add iPhone Default splash screen images

[image: screen shot of images]

Answer (score 2):

Open your Utility view and check the appropriate properties.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a few things to double check here.

First lets check that your **Deployment Info** is correct. Make sure that the **Device** is set to `Universal` otherwise it will only load in iPhone and have the `x2` option on iPad. To do this do as `Haakon` has recommend - also see image. Whilst you're there check that your **Deployment Target** is iOS 7 as you have specified it is for iOS 7 (So I assume your app is iOS 7 only)

[image]

I suspect that the **Device** is set to `iPhone` and that your **Deployment Target** is set to something below iOS7. Once you have the correct **Deployment Info** you should have settings like below in image assets catalog in your launchImages. If not look at the right hand side of this image notice the extra check boxes that you can select. Selecting these should add remove the relevant images.

[image]

Comment: It is only iPhone app, thanks for your answer but it is not working for me, i am not making iPad app or universal app.

Comment: @Nico you need to rephrase your question as it sounds like you want an iPad launch image. Not an iPhone app that is running in `x2` mode on the iPad. Please rephrase to include exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If iPhone splash is not showing up then it may be an issue of incorrect order of orientation in info.plist file. You can correct it simply by removing all check from selected orientation and then start selection from the top.
You can see a detailed answer here
http://www.folio3.com/blog/resolve-iphone-splash-screen-showing-ios-8-error/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't set up your application to be universal. Go to project settings and check if you have set the app to be Universal

[image]