# How to display splash image in ios 7 & ios6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, splash-screen

I am working on ios 7 & ios 6 3.5 inches and 4 inches screen for ios. I am working on a splash screen for both versions. In ios 7 4-inches screen it display the proper way. In iOS 6 with a 4-inch screen it is not display properly. I have issues with alignment. iOS 7 with 3.5 inches is also getting some alignment issues. But iOS 6 with 3.5 inches it displays find. I dont know how to fix the alignment issues. This is my sample code:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
{
    splashView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548)];
    splashView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"screens copy.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:splashView];
    splashView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
}
else
{
    splashView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"small-screen1.PNG"];
    [self.view addSubview:splashView];
    splashView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `Launch Images`.This is for Splash Screen functionality.

Comment: have you designed 2 splash images?? one for iphone 4,4s(320,480) size and another for iphone 5,5s(320,568) size??

Comment: Any reason why you're creating splash screens instead of using Launch Images?

Comment: @user3222991 Plz c my answer. Its not necessary to provide splash screens via coding. You have now two methodologies to implement splash screens and app icons: **Asset Catalog** or **Old School**

Comment: @user3222991 were you able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 7):

Hope this would help you see through your problem:

**Splash Screens**

[image: Splash Screens Info]

The image displays the naming convention of splash screens.
You can either use assets catalog or go old school.

**Update**

Old pattern would be helpful for the iPhone app developed in X-code 5. To implement this-

Uncheck from Launch Image Assets

[image: Update]
and add iPhone Default splash screen images

[image: Update2]

**Hint**

[Check out this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567993/xcode-5-launch-images-not-loading-in-ipad-of-iphone-app)

Comment: @madLokesh.thanks for your response.iam applying to given ur answer.But same problem getting

Comment: @user3222991 could you edit your question and post the screenshot as well. Also, plz confirm do you have the relative images of the same as well. Use the 'eye' icon to check whether images are being loaded properly.

Comment: my image dimension for  4 inches screen "640*1136 pixels" amd 3.5 inches screen image dimension "640*960 pixels"

Comment: Another important tip: Avoid using spaces in image nomenclature. Use special characters like _ , - or ~

Comment: what about non retina. Do uyou have 320 x 480 as well

Comment: @user3222991 have you disbaled "Show status bar on application launch".If not then plz do.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the different size of launch images in  `Images.xcassets -> LaunchImage` in your project using Xcode. That will solve your problem. No need to manually detect version & take overheads.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just drag and drop 2 splash images of size (640*960)Default.png and (640*1136)Default-568h@2x.png.

then select Use Asset Catalog in Launch Images option in `Targets -> General`.

And your splash screen will be displayed properly

[image]

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Default.png & Default-568h@2x.png. It will be automatically shown as splash screen.